# Android AllowBackup Error

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

These are my codes after enabling allowBackup

```
<application
            android:name=".utils.MyApplication"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

And when I got the output, I encountered the following problems with the following

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:20:9-36
    is also present at [me.itangqi.waveloadingview:library:0.3.5] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-35 value=(true).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-55:19 to override.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please use replace in yout manifest

Declare header like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourpackage"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Than add to your application tag the following attribute:

```
<application
    .
    .
    .
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup" />
```